# TeamCity job, run step only if a previous one has failed?

Tags: teamcity

We're using TeamCity 7 and wondered if it's possible to have a step run only if a previous one has failed?  Our options in the build step configuration give you the choice to execute only if all steps were successful, even if a step failed, or always run it.

Is there a means to execute a step only if a previous one failed?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you need to add a build step (powershell, command line etc) which will get the result of last build using [TeamCity REST API](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin) and then execute/dont execute your code.

Comment: There is a feature request to make the build status available to buildsteps: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-17975 (you can upvote it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Theres no way to setup a step to execute only if a previous one failed.

The closest I've seen to this, is to setup a build that has a "Finish Build" trigger that would always execute after your first build finishes. (Regardless of success or failure).

Then in that second build, you could use the TeamCity REST API to determine if the last execution from the first build was successful or not. If it wasn't successful then you could whatever it is you want to do.

Answer (score 10):

As a work around it is possible to set a variable via a command line step that only runs on success which can be checked later.

[image]

```
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.BUILD_STATUS' value='SUCCESS']"
```

This can then be queried inside a powershell step that is set to run even if a step fails.

[image]

```
if($env:BUILD_STATUS -ne "SUCCESS"){

}
```

Comment: it's does not work for me, becouse first step used command line and the second one used PowerShell, it's does not support on linux hosts. If rewrite it into bash, it's not working anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised that TeamCity does not support it out of the box in 2021. But API gives you a lot usefull features and you can do it

As a solution you need to write bash script and call TeamCity API inside

1. setup API key in MySettings & Tools => Access token
2. create env variable with API token
3. create a step in your configuration with Execute step: Even if some of the previous steps failed
4. build own container with jq or use any existing container with jq support
5. place this bash script

```
    #!/bin/bash
    set -e -x
    
    declare api_response=$(curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer %env.teamcity_internal_api_key%" %teamcity.serverUrl%/app/rest/latest/builds?locator=buildType:%system.teamcity.buildType.id%,running:any,canceled:all,count:2\&fields=build\(id,status\))
    
    declare current_status=`echo ${api_response} | jq '.build[0].status'`
    declare prev_status=`echo ${api_response} | jq '.build[1].status'`
    
    if [ "$current_status" != "$prev_status" ]; then
            do you code here
    fi
```

some explanation of code above. with API call you get 2 last builds of current buildType. This is last build and previous build. After you assign variable with statuses and compare them in if statement. If you need to run some code in case of current build failed use

```
if [ "$current_status" = "FAILURE" ]; then
    write your code here
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is Webhooks.

This [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8948-web-hooks-tcwebhooks-) can send webhook to an URL if build fails too.
On the webhook side, you can handle some actions, for example, send notification.

Answer (score 0):

In `2023.05`, there is [Run Steps Only for Failed Builds﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2023.05/what-s-new-in-teamcity.html#Run+Steps+Only+for+Failed+Builds)

[image]